# How do I handle an unreachable database server gracefully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that is primarily in mysql, but for a few pages needs to connect to another mssql server.   I have sucessfully done this, but as I develop on a mac laptop, and the sql server is on another host, it sometimes is not available.   Is there a graceful way to handle the connection when the server is not available? Ie, I still want the development and tests to run the parts that do not depend on that server.

This could also be handy in case the production rails app loses connectivity with the ms sql server - It might be nice then to be able to catch the error and display a nice "Server unavailable" message...  but still allow the rest of the app that does not depened on that database to function.

Comment: I am not a rails expert, but I imagine you have some point in the code where you open a database connection. You can check whether the connection was successful there and output an appropriate message. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, sure, but I don't know when in the rails stack that connect is handled - when the server is started or when the page is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into using a before filter on the pages that need database access. When you detect that the DB is down redirect to a non database page and flash an error message.

```
  before_filter :check_for_database

  def check_for_database
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection {|con| con.active?}
    rescue => err
      flash[:error] = "The database is down, please use pages that dont require database access."
      redirect_to :controller => 'home'
      return
    end
```

This was inspired by a post on the RailsForum [here](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=14294).